# erro Portugol... sou novato, primeiro vez aqui

Tags: portugol

Fala Galera, blx... sou novo nisso, bem novo na verdade... enfim, estou com um erro no Portugol, e realmente não entendo o que está errado, está pedindo pra colocar '(' mas já está lá... desculpa aí, pq sei que isso é uma besteira, mas tou apanhando, já refiz o código e continua a mesma coisa... como estou bem verde nesse mundo, não tenho certeza se é algum Bug... Já agradeço pelo apoio, vlwwwww

```
programa
{

    funcao inicio()
    {
        inteiro contador=0
        cadeia cliente[][]= {{"João","São Paulo","(11)9999-5241"},{"Maria","Ribeirão Preto","(16)9999-8596"},{"Ana","Manaus","(92)9999-8574"}}

        faca{
            escreva("Cliente: " + cliente[contador][0]+"Cidade: "+[contador][1]+"N° de Telefone: "+[contador][2])
            contador++
        }enquanto(contador<=2)
    }
}
```

erro está na linha 10 - escreva("Cliente: " - ... A expressão não foi iniciada corretamente. Insira o caracter '(' para corrigir o problema.
mas como dá pra ver, está lá o maldito... e nos outros exemplos que fiz, deu certo... agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: Não deveria ser:
`escreva("Cliente: " + cliente[contador][0]+"Cidade: "+ cliente[contador][1]+"N° de Telefone: "+ cliente[contador][2])`?

Comment: puta meu... kkkkk vlw... como disse, tou aprendendo... achei que o problema era no '('.... vlw bro.. ajudou pacas, obrigado \m/